# Error in Eclipse ADT Bundle :Failed to create a new project

Tags: android, eclipse

when i create a new android project , it shows me an error and cannot complete the process of creation , this is a screenshot :[image]

Help plz

Comment: Um, click "Install/Upgrade" and it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem before and this the solution :

1. Edit this file :

`<your_sdk_location>/tools/templates/activities/BlankActivity/template.xml`

1. Comment the 7th line:

   `<!--<dependency name="appcompat" version="v7" />-->`
2. save the file

**Then**

1. Edit : `<your_sdk_location>/tools/templates/activities/MasterDetailFlow/template.xml`
2. Comment the 8th and 9th lines :

   `<!--<dependency name="appcompat" version="v4" />-->`

   `<!--<dependency name="android-support-v4" revision="8"  />-->`
3. Save the file

Finally, restart Eclipse .i wish it helps you